# Build failed with an exception Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ASCII

Tags: android, android-build, android-build-type

I have upgraded to API 27 and build tools. Previously I was using API 22.

after upgrading to SDK 27 I got error that I have to use support library similar to level 27. I have downloaded Support repository version 47.0.0 through SDK manager and finally this is my gradle setting. What should I do to resolve the following error:

Build.gradle(Module:app)

```
/*
 *  Copyright 2017 Rozdoum
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 */

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
//        mavenCentral()

    }

}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rozdoum.socialcomponents"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 27
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // Support libraries
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'

    // MVP
    implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:mvp:3.1.0' // Plain MVP

    // Social
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0'

    // Images
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle(Project:Sportwall6)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta02'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The Following is the build error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\android\sportswall6\sportswall6\app\build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:226)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:48)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor$1.run(BuildScriptProcessor.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:186)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:226)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:186)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:695)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 56s
```

[!Build:output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgpuS.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgpuS.png)

Also the error pops in gradle compatibility:

[image: Also the error pops in gradle compatibility:]

After migrating to AndroidX there are many errors:

[image: Errors after migrating to androidX]

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest you -> Move to [**`AndroidX`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate). You can migrate an existing project to ***AndroidX*** by selecting **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** from the menu bar.

Upgrade to

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29

    }
```

`build.gradle` Project section

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1' // Upgrade from 3.1.2
```

Your **dependencies** will be

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
 implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
 annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

For Glide

```
RequestManager requestManager = Glide.with(YourActivity.this);
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = requestManager.load("URL");
requestBuilder.into(imageViewOBJ);
```

Comment: Sir migrating to androidX doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @Paul'somgHardware Upgrade your dependencies version. Check my Glide case.